# Xpath multiple attributes from different nodes

Tags: xpath

What's wrong with this xpath line added below:

```
/holiday[starts-with(@code,'A')/holidaytype[1]/duration[@period=(15)]
```

I'm trying to filter by holiday code and then by the number of day(period).

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `/` and a `]`. Look:

```
/holiday[starts-with(@code,'A')/holidaytype[1]/duration[@period=(15)]
 ^                             ^
 ^-- missing here              ^-- and "]" here
```

In the first case, it can be a `//` or `//*/`. So, try:

```
//holiday[starts-with(@code,'A')]/holidaytype[1]/duration[@period=(15)]
```

Comment: The `/` is not necessarily missing.

Comment: Agreed. I made the assumption based on the fact that he is searching for a `holiday` with starting code 'A', seems fair to believe that there are other `holiday`s.